# many to many count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

```
User.rb
has_many :votes
has_many :photos


Photo.rb
has_many :votes
belongs_to :user

Vote.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :photo
```

I want to list the users who voted a photo. But this list must contain the information about how many times a user voted the photo. For example when i go to url photos/5/statistics There must be a list like below:

```
1) User1   voted 30 times
2) User432 voted 15 times
3) User43  voted 12 times
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: to get the requested list, you are not specifying anything about which photos were voted on, so for the first user example, it would just be `User.find(1).votes.count #=> 30`

Comment: I dont want user's all votes just the votes that he used for specific photo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using group_by would be one way of doing it

For example:

```
Photo.first.votes.group_by(&:user).each do |user, votes| 
  puts "User #{user.id} voted #{votes.count} times"
end
```

Comment: While this works nicely, it does a query on the users table for each vote. Consider this, if performance is an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you are operating from within the Photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def voting_list
    votes.joins(:user).group(:user).count
  end
  ...
```

This will get you a OrderedHash like the following:

```
{<user_object_1> => 14, <user_object_2> => 33, ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to find out how many times a single user voted for a specific photo, you could do something like:

```
user = User.find_by_some_option
photo = user.photos.first
photo.votes.find{|vote| vote.user == user}.count
```